# IOS/Core Data: Retrieve single user object from entity

Tags: ios, core-data

I am trying to retrieve a user object for the primary app user in order to have access to the user's name, photo etc.

The code below returns null.  Is this valid code for retrieving an object?  If not, it may be that the user info is not getting stored properly in core-data in the first place....if only you could easily view the underlying sql-lite file--but that is another matter.  However, I'd like to rule out an issue with the code that retrieves the user object.

```
- (User *)getUserInfo:(NSNumber *)userid
inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    User *user = nil;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"User"];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userid == %@",userid];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"userid" ascending:YES];
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *matches = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
     if (!matches || [matches count] > 1) {
        // handle error
         }  else {
       user = [matches lastObject];
    }
    return user;
}
//This is returning null currently.  Is there an error visible somewhere?
```

Edit:

This is how it is called:

```
//in viewdidload
    _managedObjectContext = [myModel sharedInstance].managedObjectContext;
   NSNumber *useridnum =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"userid"];
  User *user = [self getDemoInfo:useridnum
            inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];

    NSLog(@"user is%@",user);//logs as null
```

Comment: is your _managedObjectContext correct? also, check if error is nil, if not print error.description

Comment: The above method is called from viewdidload and I think it is correct.

Comment: have you checked that that error is nil?

Comment: also have you checked that the userId is valid and you passing it right?

Comment: it logs out as a valid number i.e. 2.  The predicate logs out as userid==2

Comment: Try removing the predicate and just retrieving all of the `User` objects and logging them.  Check that the `userid` you are looking for.  Also, relying on the `description` method to implicitly convert your `NSNumber` to a string is icky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way your user will stay nil if the [matches count] > 1 is true , so check that you didn't made duplicated user objects with the same id